# Calculus II, Curve length question.

Tags: calculus, integration

Find the length of the curve
$x= \int_0^y\sqrt{\sec ^4(3 t)-1}dt, \quad 0\le y\le 9$

A bit stumped, without the 'y' in the upper limit it'd make a lot more sense to me.

Advice or solutions with explanation would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\frac{dx}{dy} = \sqrt{\sec^4{3 y}-1}$$

Arc length is then

$$\begin{align}\int_0^9 dy \sqrt{1+\left ( \frac{dx}{dy} \right )^2}  &= \int_0^9 dy\, \sec^2{3 y} \\ &= \frac13 \tan{27} \end{align}$$

Comment: Correct, Thank you Ron.

Comment: @user77708 see the [fundamental theorem of calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus).

Comment: @user77708: you're welcome.  Please remember that if you found this solution useful to click the checkmark under the upvote total to accept the solution.